# Directory recursion only goes one directory deep

Tags: python, recursion

I'm making a script in Python to remove all leftover .exe files from compiling stuff:

```py
import os

main_dir = '../RemoveExes'


def remove_all_in_dir(path):
    print(f'Currently in {path}. Listdir:', os.listdir(path))
    for current_name in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(current_name):
            print(f'{path}/{current_name} is a directory. Entering')
            remove_all_in_dir(f'{path}/{current_name}')
        elif current_name.endswith('.exe'):
            print(f'Would remove: {current_name}')
        else:
            print(f'{current_name} is not an .exe or a directory. Omitting.')


remove_all_in_dir(main_dir)
```

../RemoveExes is a directory with the following structure:

```
 RemoveExes
 ├  bar
 │  ├  subdir
 │  │  ├ bulb.exe
 │  │  └ some_text.txt
 │  ├ doc.docs
 │  └ een.jpg
 ├  foo
 │  ├ exe.exe
 │  └ txt.txt
 ├ cleanup.py
 ├ prog.exe
 ├ script.py
 └ text.txt
```

The program successfully "removes" exe.exe (1 directory deep) and prog.exe (0 directories deep), but does not touch bulb.exe (2 directories deep). Is this to limit recursion in Python, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns a list of file names only, without the directory names, so you should join the directory names with the file names to form the full path names instead:

```
def remove_all_in_dir(path):
    print(f'Currently in {path}. Listdir:', os.listdir(path))
    for current_name in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, current_name)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            print(f'{full_path} is a directory. Entering')
            remove_all_in_dir(f'{full_path}')
        elif current_name.endswith('.exe'):
            print(f'Would remove: {full_path}')
        else:
            print(f'{full_path} is not an .exe or a directory. Omitting.')
```